# Are the powers and authorities in Ephesians brought under Christ's rule - the same as every nation bowing in Revelation?

Tags: revelation, authority

In the book of Ephesians we see:

> far above all rule and authority and power and dominion, and above every name that is named, not only in this age but also in the one to come. 
>   Eph 1:21
>
> His intent was that now, through the church, the manifold wisdom of God should be made known to the rulers and authorities in the heavenly realms, 
>   Eph 3:10
>
> For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms. 
>   Eph 6:12

Now in Revelation we read:

> Who will not fear you, Lord,
>       and bring glory to your name?
>   For you alone are holy.
>   All nations will come
>       and worship before you,
>   for your righteous acts have been revealed.
>   Rev 15:4

My question is: **Are the powers and authorities in Ephesians brought under Christ's rule - the same as every nation bowing in Revelation?**

Comment: May I  ask,  what prompted the question about principalities, powers, etc.?

Comment: To be honest - it was a question that came up in Bible-Study this week. I was thinking about it and hoped this forum might provide some additional insights (which it did).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Ephesians 3:10,** heavenly beings in general are meant -- angels and demons. Through the church, God "teaches" heavenly beings something of God's grace and love that they never saw before.

In **Ephesians 6:12**, it speaks of the evil beings in the spiritual realm, demonic. It specifically distinguishes between earthly and heavenly spheres of influence, telling us that the physical battles against our faith are ultimately spiritual in origin, that satanic forces are against us, operating through earthly powers and means. Satan used the seductions of the world and the flesh in his attempt to draw Jesus from the faith in the wilderness episode in Matthew 4:1-11.

In **Revelation 15:4,** it's referring to earthly governments. Jesus will come again to earth, depose all earthly kingdoms and set up His own government with members of the church ruling. See Matthew 19:27-28, Revelation 2:26-27 and 20:4-6.

Comment: So because in Eph 6:12 it is Earthly governments, and Rev 15:4 it is Earthly governments - it is kind of yes - but you're saying Rev 15:4 doesn't talk about the spiritual Realm.

Comment: Hawkeye: Ep 6:12 = spiritual gov -- "in heavenly places." Rev. 15:4 = earthly -- "all nations."

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Jesus Christ is ruler of all.

I Corinthians 15;28
And when all things shall be subdued unto him, then shall the Son also himself be subject unto him that put all things under him, that God may be all and all.

Colossians 2;8,9 
Beware lest any man spoil you through plilosophy, and vain deceit, after the rudiments of the world and not after Christ. 9 For in him dwelleth all the fulness of the Godhead bodily. 1o and ye are complete in him, which is the head of all principality and power.